# flatten a multi index in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, hierarchical

I need to set index to my rows, and when I do that, pandas automatically makes my column index hierarchical..and then I tried every flatten mathod I can search, but once I reset_index, my index for row are replaced with iloc (integers). If I use df.columns = [ my col index name], it doesn't flatten my columns' index at all..

I use pandas official docs as example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
                   'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                   'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
df.set_index('month')
```

and I get

```
       year  sale
month
1      2012    55
4      2014    40
7      2013    84
10     2014    31
```

Then I flatten the index by

```
df.reset_index()
```

Then it becomes

```
  index month   year    sale
0   0   1       2012    55
1   1   4       2014    40
2   2   7       2013    84
3   3   10      2014    31
```

(The month for row index disappeard...)
This really kills me so Im appreciate it if someone can help to make the dataframe to sth like

```
month  year  sale
1      2012    55
4      2014    40
7      2013    84
10     2014    31
```

Thanks!

Comment: I dont want multi index...but I think it's automatically created when I use set_index()?

Comment: I need to customize my row index by month in this example

Comment: So need `df = df.set_index('month').rename_axis(index=None, columns='month')` ?

Comment: !!!! It;s right! how come! THANKS A LOT

Comment: Well however, when I try df.index.name it gives me None (should have been 'month')? I still think it has something to do with the flatten..

Comment: check dupe, ther is it better explain.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

which returns

```
  month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
2      7  2013    84
3     10  2014    31
```

Comment: Yah I did that! But I also want my rows indexed by month...so I have to do set_index again and it gives me the unwanted col index...